# How to assign an interface to a reactive() object Vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

How to assign an interface to a reactive() object Vuejs 3

Interface

```
export interface ProdutoInterface {
  codigo: number
  nome: string
}
```

Component

```
const dadosProduto = reactive()
```

I can't get it to work. Would anyone know how to help me.

thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add interface like this way

#### 1. need to initialize object insize `reactive`

```
const dadosProduto = reactive<ProdutoInterface>({
 codigo: 1,
 nome: 'some string'
})
```

or

```
const dadosProduto: ProdutoInterface = reactive({
 codigo: 1,
 nome: 'some string'
})
```

#### 2. set `undefined` for `reactive`

```
let dadosProduto = reactive<ProdutoInterface | undefined>()
```

```
let dadosProduto: ProdutoInterface | undefined = reactive()
```

Comment: `reactive<T>()` returns a `Ref<T>`, so the return value can't be `T`.